# Want to create VDI but getting below error

Tags: azure

I want to create VDI in azure but I'm facing the following issue while creating windows host pool

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Common.Entities.TemplateGenericProperty`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]' for the template parameter 'newOrExistingVnet' at line '152' and column '24' is not valid. The parameter value is not part of the allowed value(s): 'existing'.'.

Comment: Unless you have some code to share, you might get a better response at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 1):

This workaround assumes that you're getting this error in the portal:

1. First manually create the Resource Group and VNet.
2. Then within the VNet, add a service endpoint to e.g. Azure AD.
3. Next
   rerun the wizard, this time choosing the Resource Group and VNet you
   previously created. The template should validate successfully